# List view does not show in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

i am trying to fetch data from SQLite to list view but my list view does not show
anything. i don't understand problem because no error in logcat.
Please give me hint or suggestion.
Here is my sample code..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.locprofile);
    ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new InteractiveArrayAdapter(this,
            getModel());
    setListAdapter(adapter);}

private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private List<Model> getModel()
{
    List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
    final MySQLiteHelper m=new MySQLiteHelper(getBaseContext());
    final List<LocWiseProfileBeans> LocWiseProfile= m.getAllLocWiseProfile();       

    for (final LocWiseProfileBeans cn : LocWiseProfile) {



    list.add(get(cn.getLocname()));
    list.add(get(cn.getSelectedprofile()));

    // Initially select one of the items
    list.get(1).setSelected(true);

    }
    return list;
}

private Model get(String s) {
    return new Model(s);
}
```

InteractiveArrayAdapter.java

```
public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

private final List<Model> list;
private final Activity context;

public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) 
{
    super(context, R.layout.locprofile, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = null;

    if (convertView == null) {


        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.locprofile, null);

        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        viewHolder.checkbox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox
                                .getTag();
                        element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                    }
                });
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));

    } else {

        view = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));

    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());


    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete:

```
private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

and try again.

Comment: And replace `setListAdapter(adapter);` by `setAdapter(adapter);`. And set a contentView

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, if he is extending a simple `Activity` he will have to call `setAdapter()` on his `ListView` object , I just assumed he extends `ListActivity`.

Comment: `setAdapter` is the method from `ListActivity`. If `setListAdapter` was an inherited method, he couldn't retrict the visibility like that

Comment: @njzk2 `ListActivity` doesn't have a method `setAdapter()`, `ListView` has this method. He probably extended a simple `Activity` and tried to use the method `setListAdapter()` from `ListActivity` that doesn't exist in there and when Eclipse complained he used `CTRL + 1` and simply made a private method.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I would have meant if I could read properly a class name. thanks!

Comment: @slukian  thank you very much.actually i forgot to extend the listActvity.... thank you very much guys!